# Managing X10 devices from Java

Tags: java, x10

What is the best open-source library to manage X10 devices from Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Java X10 Project](http://www.agaveblue.org/projects/x10/).

You might also want to take a look at [HomeRun](http://homerun.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

We are working on Freedom, an open source building automation framework developed by University of Trento, DISI Department (Italy) extensible through plugins (http://freedom.disi.unitn.it/). You can use Freedom as backend and develop your own plugins over it without starting from scratch. It's a young project but we like contributors :)

Answer (score 0):

[Pragmatic Programmer](http://pragmaticautomation.com/cgi-bin/pragauto.cgi/Monitor/Devices/BubbleBubbleBuildsInTrouble.rdoc) has some information on using lava lamps as build status indicators.  That might be worth looking at because it shows the entire setup process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to x10.

Right now, i'm using Heyu with a CM11A (under Linux/Ubuntu).

I also have a CM15A but it's harder to use (even if it works).

I've tried [domus.Link](http://domus.link.co.pt/) for the web frontend (still with Heyu as a backend) and it works quite well.

But ...
I'm thinking about making my own backend in Java (and my own front-end).

I've just found this (old : 1999) library : [Java X10](http://www.jpeterson.com/2007/05/29/x10-api-source-code/)

And this (slightly) updated version : [Automation protocol: Java X10 library (bug fixes for J.Peterson's X10 API 1.0.1)](http://geekscape.org/daisy/geekscape/113.html)

I've too found stuff about [xPL](http://xplproject.org.uk/) (there is a java server implementation) and [OpenRemote](http://www.openremote.org/display/HOME/OpenRemote), but, well, both of them are not so easy to explore (and to see what you can do or canno't do with them).